# Will angular-cli removes unused modules even if it is imported in app.module and not use it?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I need little clarification in angular cli's dead code elimination/tree shaking.

[Github](https://github.com/manojp1988/zorro-sample)

I'm planning to use ngZorro ui library. As per the docs, I need to import NgZorroAntdModule in my app.module file. It contains all the components it offers. Now if I use only some of them, will angular cli still bundle all the components in my final prod build.

I tried importing the module I require separately, it works, but still I would like to know if  angular cli's tree shaking/dead code elimination removes the unused modules even though it is imported in app.module.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a similar thing which i checked.
I included below Material Modules in my **app.module.ts**
[image]
But i am only using **mat-raised-button** which is a part of **MatButtonModule** in my code.
This is what i got in my *main* bundle when i analysed using **source-map-explorer**
[image]

> Though i included Menu, Toolbar, Icon and FormField Modules in my
>   app.module.ts, since i am not using them in the code they aren't
>   included in webpack bundle.

This is the build configuration i used -

> ng build --prod --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk --progress
>   --output-hashing=all --stats-json --source-map=true

You can analyse the bundle once its generated to see the modules that are included in the package using tools like : 
[webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer), [source-map-explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer).

- You need to generate the **stats.json** file and then you can analyse using *webpack-bundle-analyzer*
- for *source-map-explorer* you need to generate the prod build with `--source-map=true`

Optimising the build package also depends on the flags you are using for the prod build.
Refer to [Angular Build Documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) for details of the flags you can use.

Comment: I tried like you said, but could not get much information in it. I just used 'multi select' dropdown module. But it is not giving me much. How should I interpret this ?

Comment: i think it included all the modules. 3.49MB is too much. can you share the details on how you inlcuded ngZorro ui in your app.module and what modules you imported in the component. Also the details on the flags you used for building.

Comment: I have added the project in github. Link is in my question. I followed https://alligator.io/angular/bundle-size/ to do the analysis.

Comment: I have also updated the stats.json and source-map.png in the github. I think I have used wrong flags. Now size differs. Can you check this two files and let me know?

Comment: ngZorro ui library may have various modules, but you included NgZorroAntdModule and may be you are using few components from that module, in that case the whole module will be included in the bundle. That is what is shown in your images as well. In My example with Material, though i included various modules and am using only few parts from MatButtonModule, only MatButtonModule is bundled in my app.

Comment: It is like even if you are including multiple modules from ngZorro ui library but if you are using only the components from NgZorroAntdModule, only NgZorroAntdModule will be included in the app bundle and not the other modules though you included then in app.module.ts as those modules are not used in your application.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Tree-shaking can only work with libraries are built in such a way that the build optimizer can remove the unused code.

This was the case with RxJS that was not supporting tree-shaking before v5.5

NG-Zorro only has one import module (for all components) but it now supports tree-shaking since 1.x